# Does stock Android have a panorama camera feature?

Tags: camera, stock-android

I was wondering if Android has any panorama-like feature like how iOS does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends entirely on the OEM and what features they decide to put in their devices.

However, I've used a panorama feature since the beginning (2.3 Gingerbread) on my Nexus S, and have had it all the way till my 4.2 Galaxy Nexus, so I can say that the stock Android camera app has panorama, at least 2.3 onwards.

Beyond that, device specific panorama is dependent on the OEM.

You could always use third party apps, like [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=obg1.Photaf&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsIm9iZzEuUGhvdGFmIl0.) one, which supports Android 2.1 and above.

Comment: Thanks! Good response! Is photo-sphere what your talking about? Or is it something else??

Comment: PhotoSphere is only available officially on Android 4.2 so far. However, [XDA comes to your rescue](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1965895) (scroll down to about halfway through the first post, and you'll see photosphere listed as one of the backported features).

Comment: Thanks for your amazing explanations. :) BTW speaking of XDA I'll never forget this one: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JmvCpR45LKA :)